# Shell: print only required text from returned CURL request

Tags: json, shell

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat singers.txt);
do
  for j in $(cat songs.txt);
  do
    output=$(curl -d "singer=$i&song=$j" https://company_api.com/...)
    echo -e $output | tee -a out.txt
  done
done
```

This prints out:

```
{"code": "success", "data": {"singer": "John Lennon", "song": "Imagine"}}
{"code": "success", "data": {"singer": "Beatles", "song": "Yesterday"}}
```

I only want to print out:

```
"singer": "John Lennon"
"singer": "Beatles"
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you will use 'jq' to extract the data. However, the output format that you ask for is not a valid JSON, so additional filtering is needed.

If you just want to get the singer for each item:

```
    output=$(curl -d "singer=$i&song=$j" https://company_api.com/... | jq .data.singer)
    echo -e '"singer:" ' $output
```

With the result

```
"singer:" "John Lennon"
"singer:" "Beatles"
```

If you have flexibility on the output, consider replacing the output=... and echo with

```
curl -d "singer=$i&song=$j" https://company_api.com/... | jq '{ singer: .data.singer }'
```

Wiith the result forming a valid JSON document:

```
{
  "singer": "John Lennon"
}
{
  "singer": "Beatles"
}
```